# Issue in passing the data to emailTemplate ejs file

Tags: node.js, express, web, ejs

I am trying to pass the token to the email Template which is an `ejs` file i.e `emailTemplate.ejs`
But It's not getting rendered as the data instead it's getting rendered only as test i.e `token` variable is rendered as `token` text.
Here is the code:

```
sendgridMail.setApiKey(sendGridApi)

const email = async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
  let token
  if (user) {
    token = user.tokens.slice(-1)[0].token
    console.log('token before sending email ', token)
  }
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/../../views/emailTemplate.ejs')
  // TO PASS TOKEN TO EMAIL TEMPLATE EJS FILE
  ejs.renderFile(filePath, { token: token }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error in renderFile ', err)
    } else {
      // console.log('ejs data ', data)
      const message = {
        to: req.body.email,
        from: 'services@codeuino.com',
        subject: `Welcome to Donut ${req.body.name.firstName}`,
        html: data
      }
      sendgridMail.send(message).then(
        () => {
          console.log('sending email')
          next()
        },
        (error) => {
          res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send({
            error: process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY
              ? error.response.body
              : 'Setup SENDGRID_API_KEY environment variable'
          })
        }
      )
    }
  })
}
```

HERE IS EMAIL TEMPLATE EJS trying to render the URL

```
 <p>http://localhost:5000/user/activate/ <=% token %></p> // TOKEN IS NOT GETTING RENDERED HERE
```

Whreas alraedy configured as `ejs` veiw engine in `server.js`

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a ejs syntax error.
Passing a parameter to a template should look like this.

`<%= token %>`

Comment: Ahh.. a simple typo ruined my day.
Thanks a lot @stefan! you saved me.

Comment: can happen to anyone :) have a nice day